# Javascript on cloudapge - 505

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

I'am really struggling with this part.

I am trying to submit values from checkboxes into a function which gets activated when anybody clicks the button.
The function opens an URL and with the values from the checkboxes as parameters

So far so good. If I use static values for the variables called

> submitinformationMailOptIn
>
> submitcommercialMailOptin
>
> submittransactionalMailOptin

the cloudpages renders without a problem, but if I declare them with the

> var variable = document.getElementById('****');

method, the cloudpage does not render anymore and shows a 505 instead.

Do you see the error? or have you an idea how to solve it?

```
....
Write('Guten Tag '+ salesforceContactSalutation+ ' ' + salesforceContactLastName +',<br><br>'+'laut Ihren Einstellungen bekommen Sie folgende Emails:<br>');

Write('<br><form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="transactionalMailOptinBox" name="transactionalMailOptinBox"'+transactionalMailOptin+' value=""> Transaktionsmails</input>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="informationMailOptInBox" name="informationMailOptInBox"'+informationMailOptIn+' value=""> Persönliche Mails</input>
<br>  
<input type="checkbox" id="commercialMailOptinBox" name="commercialMailOptinBox"'+commercialMailOptin+' value=""> Special Deals Mails</input>
<br><br>
</input>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="upDate()"></button></form>');

var salesforceId="";
var submitinformationMailOptIn="";
var submitcommercialMailOptin="";
var submittransactionalMailOptin="";

salesforceId = Variable.GetValue("@salesforceId");

submittransactionalMailOptin = document.getElementById('transactionalMailOptinBox').value;

if(submittransactionalMailOptin===""){ submittransactionalMailOptin=""; };

submitinformationMailOptIn = document.getElementById('informationMailOptInBox').value;

if(submitinformationMailOptIn===""){ submitinformationMailOptIn=""; };

submitcommercialMailOptin = document.getElementById('commercialMailOptinBox').value;

if(submitcommercialMailOptin===""){ submitcommercialMailOptin=""; };

function upDate(){
window.location.assign("http://examplewebsite.com/exampledata?sfId="+ salesforceId +"&InformationMailOptin="+ submitinformationMailOptIn+"&CommercialMailOptin="+submitcommercialMailOptin+"&TransactionalMailOptin="+submittransactionalMailOptin);
};
```

Comment: I wonder if it is because you have null values in your inputs. `value=""`. which is causing issues in your JS as those var would then be set to null.

Comment: Just checked that. I set the value to False,True,Checked ... but it never rendered.

Comment: shouldn't `name="transactionalMailOptinBox"'+transactionalMailOptin+' value=""` instead be `name="transactionalMailOptinBox" value="'+transactionalMailOptin+'"`?

Comment: transactionalMailOptin is a variable which is set to "checked" or to "" depending on the value in the sales and service cloud.